# Change irregular header with extra whitespace

Tags: text-formatting, bioinformatics

I am working with data in [this obscure file format](https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/dosage.shtml):

```
   SNP  A1  A2   F1 I1 F2 I2 F3 I3
rs0001   A   C   0.02 0.00 1.99
```

(Note the whitespace around the first three fields)

The header is long (500k entries) and I would like to transform it into something as follows:

```
   SNP  A1  A2   F1_I1 F2_I2 F3_I3
rs0001   A   C   0.02 0.00 1.99
```

...so that it's easier to work with, with or without removing the irregular whitespace.
For reference, this is also acceptable, as long as it's consistent:

```
SNP A1 A2 F1_I1 F2_I2 F3_I3
rs0001 A C 0.02 0.00 1.99
```

Is there any way I can reformat it within Unix/Linux? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `tr` command.

Comment: I am not sure how `tr` would work in this case, since I still need the whitespace between the fields

Comment: "`tr -s`: replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the last specified ARRAY, with a single occurrence of that character". Isn't that precisely what you want?

Comment: I wouldn't call the PLINK format "obscure" as it's commonly used in bioinformatics.  Instead of helping you butcher the file (making it unreadable by bioinformatics tools that expect this format), what is it that you believe the change would make it easier for you to do? Also, note that the filename suffix of the input file is _relevant_ to interpreting the data in the file. See also https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats See also [this text](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/other#tabspace) about tabs vs. spaces in PLINK files.

Comment: @ajgringo619  No, my main problem is the whitespace between the two ID entries. `F1 I1`  refers to the same column in the following record, but most software implementations to read  delimited files will interpret it as two columns if I use whitespace as a separator. Hence why I would like to swap it with `F1_I1` (or any other character, really)

Comment: Are you sure all of the separators in your input are the same whitespace character and you don't, for example, have tabs between the pairs of `F1 I1` strings and blanks within the pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plink file format specification that you linked to contains a number of weird details.

First, there are examples where "F1 I1" and "F2 I2" clearly represent headings of two different (but related) columns:

```
    SNP  A1  A2   F1 I1       F2 I2        F3 I3
 rs0001   A   C   0.98 0.02   1.00 0.00    0.00 0.01 
 rs0002   G   A   0.00 1.00   0.00 0.00    0.99 0.01
```

But there is also the example that you've given where it looks like the `Ix` column values are missing although the headings are present:

```
    SNP  A1  A2   F1 I1 F2 I2 F3 I3
 rs0001   A   C   0.02 0.00 1.99
```

To me it's not clear whether this example is just wrong or the data can actually be formatted like that. A comment related to the `dose1` option seems to imply that it is possible to have one-column dosage data instead of the apparently normal two-column format: "Dosage data is 0..1, not 0..2 scale". To my gut feeling, it looks like the example data where only one value is given has its heading mixed up.

How to deal with imprecise specifications and data that only partially matches what you understand of the spec is always difficult. You need to decide how forgiving your data parser should be so that it handles files with slight heading issues correctly while still flagging invalid data.

Regarding your actual file processing problem: If there's some external indicator telling whether a file has single-value or two-value dosage data, I would just drop the `Ix` headings completely using any scripting or text processing language that you're familiar with, whether it's `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python` or whatever.

Comment: I think that comment refers to the way dosages are counted (`0..1` meaning that A1 = 1, A2 = 0, as compared to `0..2` where A1A1 = 2, A1A2/A2A1 = 1, A2A2 = 0; the latter is the most widespread nowadays as it allows to scale results by the number of copies of an allele, the former is probably easier to calculate starting from imputation quality scores). I do like the idea of ditching the `Ix` IDs entirely, I can probably just grep them out

Answer (score 1):

You could have `sed` overwrite the first line in place with:

```
sed -E 's/(F[[:digit:]]+) (I[[:digit:]])/\1_\2/g;q' < file 1<> file
```

That's efficient because we're only reading and writing the first line. It's only a valid thing to do because we're writing a line of the exact same length as the one we read. If there were possibly more than one space between the `Fn` and `In` and you wanted to replace them with only one `_`, you couldn't use that approach and would have to rewrite the whole file, for instance with:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(F\d+)\s+(I\d)/${1}_${2}/g if $. == 1' file
```

Which creates a new `file` as the edited copy of the original. Some `sed` implementations have copied that `-i` from `perl`. For instance, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ei '1s/(F[[:digit:]]+)\s+(I[[:digit:]])/\1_\2/g' file
```

would also work. With some other `sed` implementations, you need `-i ''`. You may also need to replace `\s` with `[[:space:]]`.

To replace any sequence of one or more whitespace characters with a single space, you can do `s/[[:space:]]+/ /g` (with `perl`, you'd need to add the `-l` option as otherwise the line delimiter which is also whitespace would be included in the pattern space and end up being replaced with a space).

Note that that regex matching is not very strict, if looks for `F<digits> I<digit>` anywhere in the line, so would find it in `PAF12 I0ther` for instance. A stricter matching could be done in `perl` with:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<!\S)(F\d+)\s+(I\d+)(?!\S)/${1}_${2}/g if $. == 1' file
```

Where we use negative look around operators to check that what precedes and follows is not a non-whitespace character.